# C++ char buffer pointer error

Tags: c++, pointers, char, buffer

I'm using a function that reads a spooled file and sets a buffer with the output.
The function returns OK state and sets `readBytes` correctly. It also notifies that the reading operation has reached the end of the file.

```
char* splFileContent = new char[3000];
ULONG readBytes;
int z = cwbOBJ_ReadSplF(splFile, splFileContent, 500, &readBytes, 0);
//z value is REACHED END OF FILE or OK if read but didn't reach the end of the file.
```

The trouble comes when trying to convert the char buffer to string, I'm getting "4Ä" as string value...[image]

I convert the char buffer to string this way:

```
stringstream s;
s << splFileContent;
string bufferContent = s.str();
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can convert to a string using `string bufferContent(splFileContent, readBytes) ;`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `splFileContent` is binary content and not printable characters.

The start of the file may contain a BOM of some sort, e.g. unicode indicator. If it is, you should read in the BOM first and then the rest of the file.

Note: unless the file read function here adds a `NULL`, be sure to append one as well.

Comment: How can I convert binary chars to ascii? Thanks.

Comment: Generally you transform the byte wide binary to a hexadecimal string two bytes wide (each character would be in the range [0-9A-F]). You could use streams, sprintf functions etc. There are several popular techniques.